# Circuit Failure How to fix it?

Tags: pcb, multimeter

I'm sorry I am very specific here, I have a problem with the charger of my motorbike dashcam and I hope you can help me fixing it (see picture and video test with multimeter).

I really have no idea of the various PCB components, I was thinking maybe to "bypass" it using the wires but before I try this extreme procedure, maybe you can help me fixing the problem in a less destructive way.

[Link to Picture and Video!](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u0cxjy8s3o26csv/AAANK0tz6cMQJt4KvANT32aWa?dl=0)

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering. Unfortunately, repair questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @user2233709 oh I'm sorry, you know where can I ask?

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately, no, I don’t know a good place for such questions. Hopefully someone might. Anyway, if you have no understanding of electronics, it will be very complicated to repair this remotely.

Comment: It's a switching regulator. Dont bypass it. You'll instantly kill the dashcam.

Comment: what is the point of the video? .... it looks like you do not allow the readings to settle before moving the probe

Comment: `I am very specific here` .... no you are not .... you don't even say what is wrong with  the charger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so first of all I can't see things about that charger that might have safety implications so be careful, probe outputs for dangerous voltages, and assume anything you haven't measured that is conductive is dangerous to touch (even and especially heat sinks).

There are two capacitors on that board that may have failed especially if it's an older part. They are the cannisters on the left. Inspect them closely for damage, and if one is damaged you can try replacing it with a similar part (same capacitance and voltage rating)

Like the comments say, that's a switching regulator. Energy is allowed to flow into the inductor from a high voltage low current source, and flows out to a low voltage high current destination.

The 8-pin circuit in the middle appears to be a controller, and if you want a better understanding of the circuit find the documentation for that chip.